# go build mistakes .go/src for go/src in looking for dependencies

Tags: go

I'm trying to install a [package from github](https://github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup). The reported errors show that `go build` looks for source files in `/go/src` rather than `.go/src` (=`$GOPATH`). Look for `/home/er/go/src/` in the error messages. How can I troubleshoot this problem?

```
~/.go/src/netbackup $ echo $GOPATH
/home/er/.go
~/.go/src/netbackup $ go version
go version go1.10.4 linux/amd64
~/.go/src/netbackup $ sudo go build
main.go:17:2: cannot find package "github.com/marcopaganini/logger" in any of:
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/github.com/marcopaganini/logger (from $GOROOT)
/home/er/go/src/github.com/marcopaganini/logger (from $GOPATH)
main.go:18:2: cannot find package "github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup/config" in any of:
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup/config (from $GOROOT)
/home/er/go/src/github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup/config (from $GOPATH)
main.go:19:2: cannot find package "github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup/execute" in any of:
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup/execute (from $GOROOT)
/home/er/go/src/github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup/execute (from $GOPATH)
main.go:20:2: cannot find package "github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup/transports" in any of:
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup/transports (from $GOROOT)
/home/er/go/src/github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup/transports (from $GOPATH)

~/.go/src/netbackup $ tree
.
├── config
│   ├── config.go
│   └── config_test.go
├── examples
│   └── restic-example.conf
├── execute
│   └── execute.go
├── flags.go
├── LICENSE
├── main.go
├── main_test.go
├── README.md
└── transports
    ├── rclone.go
    ├── rclone_test.go
    ├── rdiff_backup.go
    ├── rdiff_backup_test.go
    ├── restic.go
    ├── restic_test.go
    ├── rsync.go
    ├── rsync_test.go
    ├── transports.go
    └── transports_test.go

4 directories, 19 files

~/.go/src/logger $ tree
.
├── LICENSE
├── logger.go
└── README.md

0 directories, 3 files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in the list above.

First, the project is not cloned in the right path.
According to the error message, the compiler searches for it under `$GOPATH/src/github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup` but the project is directly cloned in `$GOPATH/src/`.

The second one is that the IDE, if I infer correctly from the question tag here as GoLand, did not automatically configured itself to the GOPATH that you have, `$HOME/.go` but rather it's configured to `$HOME/go`.

If your `GOPATH` really is `$HOME/.go`, then you should go under the IDE settings at `Settings/Preferences | Go | GOPATH` and set the `Global GOPATH` value to be the one you need.

However, if `$HOME/.go` is where Go itself is installed, or you don't have any setting for GOPATH in your shell, which you can check using `go env GOPATH`, then you should clone the project under the path that the error tells you about, or simply run `go get github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup/...`

Comment: Thanks, not sure what you mean by "IDE settings". This is all from the command line. Copying the repo frm `/src`to `/src/github.com` does not solve the problem. `$ go env GOPATH
/home/er/.go`.

Comment: You tagged the issue with "goland", which is a Go IDE from JetBrains https://www.jetbrains.com/go/ So it was not clear what you ask for. Moving on, it seems that the dependencies for your build are missing, so, as I said, use `go get github.com/marcopaganini/netbackup/...` call to get all the dependencies for it